# Fatal error while installing symfony2 in autoload.php

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to install symfony for a week now and i have plenty of errors everytime !!! 
 i couldn't find a solution to this specific error :

```
Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry' not found in C:\wamp\www\Symfony\app\autoload.php on line 35
```

here's what i have in the autoload.php file :

```
$loader->register();AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(function($class) use ($loader) {
$loader->loadClass($class);return class_exists($class, false);});
```

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have registered `Doctrine\Common` namespace like this in `autoload.php`:

```
$loader = new UniversalClassLoader();
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    'Symfony'           => array(__DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/src', __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles'),
    'Sensio'            => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles',
    'JMS'               => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles',
    'Doctrine\\Common'  => __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine-common/lib',
    'Doctrine\\DBAL'    => __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine-dbal/lib',
    'Doctrine'          => __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine/lib',

    // more lines here...

));
```

It is important that `Doctrine\Common` namespaces is above `Doctrine` (look here - [autoload.php from github](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.0/app/autoload.php)).

Comment: my autoload.php looks like the one in the link you gave me !!! but always the same error ! I tried to install it in UBUNTU but i have a similar error ! Is it a problem in my laptop Configuration ???

Comment: Hard to say. Do you have required files in `vendors` ? Have you run `./bin/vendors install` to get required updates from git? Do you have php version 5.3.2+ ? I don't think it is a problem with laptop configuration in your case.

Comment: Finally it's working :) 
Even with Xampp (PHP5.3.8) working very good, all the php samples giving with xampp were working, i had to install php again, because i had the msg php is not installed !
Also, when extracting and moving folders from a folder to another some documents were lost !! i had to recheck every folder ! 

Thank you very much though :)

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you downloaded symfony without vendors? So this error occurs, because required files are missing.